# Is there a way to get Node's path.join() to return a './tmp' directory

Tags: node.js, path

An npm library I'm using has this function `path.join(options.pdf_path, fileName + '.pdf')`. I'll be running this in a docker container.

I'm trying to pass in `./tmp/` as the `options.pdf_path` but my logs are showing that it's returning `tmp/fileName.pdf` when I want it to return `./tmp/fileName.pdf`.

Is `path.join()`'s normalizer always going to remove the `./` from the beginning of my file path or is there a way to ensure that it remains unchanged?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any reason why you do not manually add `./` since it's your requirement? e.g. `./${path.join......}`

Comment: The `path.join` is being used in an npm library so I can't do anything to alter that, so trying to find a way to "trick" it in the `options.pdf_path`

Comment: specifying the library you are using in these kind of questions will get you answers much easier